# 2d array with std::vector in c++ - container

Tags: c++, vector, graph, containers

I am trying to make a 2d array by making a vector of vectors of EdgeWeights (it is for an adjacency matrix), but am having trouble understanding how the nested containers function.

I am constructing the before mentioned structure as such,

```
std::vector<std::vector<EdgeWeight> > M = 
    std::vector<std::vector<EdgeWeight>>(num_edges, std::vector<EdgeWeight>(num_nodes));
```

but am having trouble understanding what is happening. Why is do the parameters go where they do an in that order? Also, once this is created I don't understand how to access an element of the container. How does this work?

EDIT: My guess at adding an edgeweight to the adjacency matrix is this

```
M.at(u).at(v) = weight; //M is the matrix.
```

Comment: _"My guess at adding an edgeweight to the adjacency matrix is this"_ And did it work? Alternatively you can write: `M[u][v] = weight;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The template class `std::vector` has the following constructors

```
explicit vector(size_type n, const T& value, const Allocator& = Allocator());
explicit vector(size_type n, const Allocator& = Allocator());
```

The first constructor allows to define an object that contains `n` elements that initially initialized by `value`

Instead of definition

```
std::vector<std::vector<EdgeWeight> > M = 
    std::vector<std::vector<EdgeWeight>>(num_edges, std::vector<EdgeWeight>(num_nodes));
```

you could write simply

```
std::vector<std::vector<EdgeWeight> > M( num_edges, std::vector<EdgeWeight>(num_nodes) );
```

So in this definition you create object `M` that contains `num_edges` elements of type `std::vector<EdgeWeight>`  that are initialized by `std::vector<EdgeWeight>(num_nodes)`. That is each element in turn is a vector of `num_nodes` elements that are created using the second constructor.

You may imagine this as creating of a matrix with `num_edges` rows and `num_nodes` columns. Only each row is an object of type `std::vector<EdgeWeight>` and you need to call a constructor for it that to specify how many columns must be created in the row.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really understood what you were doing but

```
std::vector<std::vector<EdgeWeight> > M
```

this here is a 2d vector which can contain another vector of type EdgeWeight i.e.

```
std::vector<EdgeWeight> N;  
N.push_back(this value here is passed to the constructor of you EdgeWeight class);
```

and then:

```
M.push_back(N);
```